# how can I turn a number into the value of a new dataframe?

Tags: pandas

I am trying to turn a scalar into a dataframe structure assigning a column name and an index name.

I have the following scalar (in concrete a numpy.float64) : -0.090058

and I would like to turn it into a df:

```
       decimal
ratio  -0.090058
```

I thought it was going to be straight forward. This is what I have tried unsuccesfully:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(value,index='ratio',columns='decimal')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you were almost there:

```
In [222]: pd.DataFrame(value,index=['ratio'],columns=['decimal'])
Out[222]:
        decimal
ratio -0.090058
```

you can also do it this way:

```
In [223]: pd.DataFrame(index=['ratio']).assign(decimal=value)
Out[223]:
        decimal
ratio -0.090058
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution with passing `dict`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'decimal':value},index=['ratio'])
print (df)
        decimal
ratio -0.090058
```